# Text Indexing and Slicing

Tags: python

I am supposed to transform each sentence such that we only keep the words between the third and the third-last word (inclusive) and skip every second word on the way.

Text in `jane_eyre_sentences.txt`:

```
My feet they are sore and my limbs they are weary
Long is the way and the mountains are wild
Soon will the twilight close moonless and dreary
Over the path of the poor orphan child
```

My Code is shown as below:

```
for line in open("jane_eyre_sentences.txt"):
  line_strip = line.rstrip()
  words = line_strip.split()
  if len(words)%2 == 0:
    print(" ".join(words[2:-4:2]), ""+ "".join(words[-3]))
  else:
    print(" ".join(words[2:-3:2]),""+ "".join(words[-3]))
```

My Output:

```
they sore my they
the and mountains
the moonless
path poor
```

Expected Output:

```
they sore my they
the and mountains
the close
path the
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending the wrong word for even lines. You must change this line

```
print(" ".join(words[2:-4:2]), ""+ "".join(words[-3]))
```

to

```
print(" ".join(words[2:-4:2]), ""+ "".join(words[-4]))
```

You can also get rid of the unnecessary empty string and the second `join` as it is a single word anyway:

```
print(" ".join(words[2:-4:2]), words[-4])
```

Comment: This works, thank you! Both solutions work, the second one is simpler!